# How to I get token?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, axios

I am trying to implement token based authentication. The code below works on tutorial I'm watching but when I run it, I can't don't get any token. Here is the code :

```
  axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://localhost:3002";

  const [userLogin, setUserLogin] = useState({
    username: "",
    password: "",
  });

  const { username, password } = userLogin;

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const data = userLogin;
    
    const response = await axios.post("/login", data, {
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
       credentials : 'include'
    });
  };
```

Preview on Network :
[image]

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is the actual problem?

Comment: it doesn't give me a token.

Comment: When you try to call endpoint localhost:3002/login trought postman do you see any response?

Comment: I tried with Postman and it gave me all `login` objects.
Here is the objects :

[
    {
        "username": "a",
        "password": "a",
        "id": 1
    } ]
there is a few login object like that

Comment: So the problem is not in your react app, code wich is running on server doesn't return you token. You have to change server side code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the question clearly but I think that you need to do this.

yourwebscript (request) > backend server running for example nodejs js > the backend server returns a token (you send username and password).

Now you have the token and you can make the request with token.

I think I have understand it, you need to read de response with e.responseJSON in the success or completed section.